# Masks for descriptorMatcher

Tags: c++, opencv

How masks should be arranged in [cv::DescriptorMatcher::match](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d39/classcv_1_1DescriptorMatcher.html#a695c0aceafc907c024c24a0b5cdff758)?

I am using a BruteForce matcher with multiple train images and single query. I want to match against all train images except a single one which is the query image it self that I know its index in the descriptions list.

Answer (score 0):

The first variant of the method [cv::DescriptorMatcher::match](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d39/classcv_1_1DescriptorMatcher.html#a0f046f47b68ec7074391e1e85c750cba) describes the `mask` parameter more clearly:

> Optional mask (or masks) can be passed to specify which query and
> training descriptors can be matched. Namely, queryDescriptors[i] can
> be matched with trainDescriptors[j] only if mask.at(i,j) is
> non-zero.

So, you should set that particular index to `0` to exclude it.

If I understand correctly, you are trying to find matches in the training set itself, so if you do it in one-shot rather than querying one by one, the `mask` would have all zeros in the diagonal.